# Permuting $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $k$ elements appear between $1$ and $2$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> Let $n \geq k + 2$. How many permutations of the set $\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ are there,
> such that exactly $k$ elements appear between $1$ and $2$?

My solution is to first of all count those sets where the $1$ appears before the $2$ for simplicity (then double the answer at the end). A permutation can be constructed by first filling in the $1$, for which there are $n-1-k$ potential places. For each of these, we then fill in the $k$ values after this $1$; there are ${n-2 \choose k}$ ways to choose these $k$ values, and each of these can be permuted $k$! ways. We are left with $n-2-k$ values to fill in "outside" the $1$ and $2$, and can again permute these in any way. Finally, we may apply this same process except with the $1$ and $2$ swapped, doubling the total. Therefore, this gives $2 \times (n-1-k) \times {n-2 \choose k}k! \times (n-2-k)! = 2 \times {n-2 \choose k}k! \times (n-1-k)!$.

This is wrong, and the correct answer is $2 \times (n-k-1) \times (n-2)!$. **I understand the reasoning behind this so I'm not asking for an explanation of the correct answer**. However I can't spot the flaw in my wrong answer! It is considerably larger so I'm overcounting some solutions somewhere, but I can't see where.

Comment: Use the formula for binomial numbers.

Comment: Hard for me to edit, as of now, but I suggest that you use the tag ([tag:solution-verification]) . Also, please remove the ([tag:fake-proofs]) tag. I don't think it applies to your question.

Comment: +1 to your question for very fine work shown.  First see the answer of Ritam_Dasgupta.  Further, in my opinion, your analysis was not only accurate, but also valid, each step of the way.

Comment: How did you determine that your solution is "considerably larger"? You should look for an error **there**.

Answer (score 3):

Your obtained answer is correct, they evaluate to the same expression.